# `AppleCamera` used by Google Chrome even with all extensions+apps disabled/tabs closed

Tags: google-chrome, microphone, privacy

I'm noticing that Google Chrome (`Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)` — current version as of writing this question) has enabled my MBP camera and, perhaps, the microphone:

```
$ lsof | grep "AppleCamera"
Google    1466 areynolds  txt       REG                1,6     354304 4305421720 /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/AppleCamera.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AppleCamera
$ ps -p 1466
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1466 ??         0:38.47 /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

I have no tabs open (just one window, which defaults to https://www.google.com). I have also disabled all Chrome extensions and apps.

I went into Chrome's settings and set the switches to require sites that use the camera and microphone to first ask my permission.

How do I stop Google Chrome from enabling my camera and microphone without permission? If relevant or useful, I am running OS X 10.13.4.

**EDIT**

Perhaps an alternative or more general question is: Given that this application is accessing the camera without permission, is there a way in OS X to block access to the `AppleCamera` device (or any particular device, generally) on a per-application level, as a general security measure? Is there a way to lock down OS X to this degree (perhaps via LDAP attributes used via OS X Server/Open Directory)?

Comment: Is the green light on for camera?

Comment: No, but Chrome is using the camera, according to `lsof`

Comment: Not a fix but you’ll be happy to hear that Chrome is NOT using the camera hardware. The green light is hardwired into the camera and therefore the camera can not be activated without the green light being activated.

Comment: That's not what the operating system says.

Comment: unfortunately no answer here, but asked before.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177044/camera-used-by-chrome-even-when-not-active

Comment: Can you reinstall chrome?

Comment: don't install Google products on your Mac. On my system your `lsof` shows no output. Firefox was rewritten in Rust and now much faster.

Comment: While it's not likely that the camera is actually on and recording, because the light is off, it's still a bit unnerving to see how many files Chrome has open. Just opened Chrome to the Google  search page, and I see **919 files held open by Chrome**. Yikes!

Answer (score 8):

You have presumed too much from the software's name. The CoreMediaIO Device Abstraction Layer (DAL) `Apple.Camera.plugin` does not control the camera, and wouldn't know how to control it even if you gave it permission. It has one job: to manage video (and muxed) streams from video devices that are already streaming. With no hardware driver running in the kernel, there can be no power sent to the camera--no kext, no power, no picture: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012293-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

So, why is it running? It helps avoid a little wait time when it is called into actual use. It's been there for well over ten years, and if `AppleCamera.plugin` was a vector for intrusion, we'd have heard much sooner.